# Javascript popup

Tags: 2013, javascript, popup

I am using the below code to create a pop for pages.  When you right click and select print preview, the preview is of the page behind the pop up as well as the pop.  Is it possible to just preview the pop up and ultimately print only the content in the pop up?  I have noticed that the display pop up for list items support this and only the pop up is printed and previewed.

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('somepage.aspx',RefreshOnDialogClose,null,null,'Some Page Header')">
```